# Manually return access denied error from SignalR OnConnected method

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

In my code, I'm overwriting the OnConnected method of my SignalR hub. In there, I want to return a distinguishable error message to the client, if he or she is not allowed to access the hub. For now, I just throw an exception, which appears as an error 500 "Internal Server Error" on the client side. From the client side, I want to show an access denied message, when the user doesn't have proper rights. However, I want the client to try to reconnect to the server, if any other error happened while connecting.

As I said, right now, I just catch the `$.connection.hub.start().fail` event:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(/* ... */).fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err.context.status);
    console.log(err);
}
```

Now, whatever goes wrong on connecting, `err.context.status` will always be 500. Is there any way to make my `OnConnected` method return anything useful to the client?

```
public override async Task OnConnected() {
    if(!userCanAccess())
        throw new AccessViolationException("You are not allowed to access this site.");

    await base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: Can it be that you just broadcast that message to your client and simple after broadcast close the connection?

Comment: That would be an idea. As a workaround, I now filter the error message content for the "You are not allowed..." string on the client side. It's hacky and not very nice, but it works.

Comment: There is another option to this to be better. You can create a "hublog" that can always connect to your client and broadcast serversentevents like this 500 error an others events functioning like a log. But yes, you need to continue research to get the real response for your question!